# How convert svg to png on server side and stream to client?

Tags: node.js

I tried something like this.

```
var svg = '<svg>..</svg>';

im.convert([svg, 'png:-'],
function(err, stdout){
  if (err) throw err;
   res.send(stdout);
});
```

But is not working.Have any ideas?)))

Answer (score 0):

There is another npm module to this task. here it's [svgexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgexport)

install it: `npm install --save svgexport`

```
var svgexport = require('svgexport');

svgexport.render(datafile, function(err, stdout){
  if (err) throw err;
     res.append('Content-Type', 'image/png');
     res.send(stdout);
});
```

never tested the code. but it suppose to work.

Cli usage;

```
svgexport input.svg output.png 64x
svgexport input.svg output.png 1024:1024
```

Comment: yes, but the client still receives a response svg format((